# Need some help changing a program to an object oriented program

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I have been creating a program as part of an assignment and have reached a point where I have been asked to alter the written structure to an object oriented program. This means creating a class with methods.

Here is the question/task itself:

[Question/Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1jTp.png)

Here is the program code without alteration:

```
def make_album(id_num, name, band, price):
    """creates and returns a dictionary with keys id_num, name, band, and 
    price, with values populated directly from the function parameters."""
    album_dict = {}
    values = [int(id_num), name, band, float(price), 0, None, None]
    keys = ['id_num', 'name', 'band', 'price', 'total_sales', 
              'first_date_recorded', 'last_date_recorded']
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        album_dict[keys[i]] = values[i]
    return album_dict

def add_sales(album, date, daily_sales):
    """updates the given album dictionary by incrementing the total_sales 
    value by the given number of sales for that day"""
    if album['first_date_recorded'] == None:
        album['first_date_recorded'] = date
        album['last_date_recorded'] = date
    elif date > album['last_date_recorded']:
        album['last_date_recorded'] = date
    elif date < album['first_date_recorded']:
        album['first_date_recorded'] = date
    album['total_sales'] += daily_sales

def print_album(album):
    """Prints the given album in a format like the following, where the 
    first and last lines are both made of 40 hyphen ('-') characters"""
    print('-' * 40)
    print('Album Name: {}'.format(album['name']))
    print('Band: {}'.format(album['band']))
    print('Purchase Price: ${:.2f}'.format(album['price']))
    print('First Recorded Sale: {}'.format(album['first_date_recorded']))
    print('Last Recorded Sale: {}'.format(album['last_date_recorded']))
    print('Total Sold: {}'.format(album['total_sales']))
    print('-' * 40)

def extract_album(lines, index):
    """takes a list of lines and an index into that list and returns a 
    album dictionary"""
    id_num, name, band, price = lines[(index + 1):(index + 5)]
    album_dict = make_album(id_num, name, band, price)
    return album_dict

def extract_all_albums(lines):
    """returns a list of albums in the same order as they are encountered 
    input lines list"""
    album_dict_list = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line == '<album>':
            album = extract_album(lines, i)
            album_dict_list.append(album)
    return album_dict_list

def read_sales(lines, albums):
    """locates the sales section if there is one and for each sales record 
    it should call the add_sales function on the appropriate album to update 
    the number of albums sold"""
    start_tag = 0
    end_tag = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line == '<sales>':
            start_tag = i
        elif line == '</sales>':
            end_tag = i
    for line in lines[(start_tag + 1):(end_tag)]:
        date, id_num, sales = line.split(',')
        for album in albums:
            if album['id_num'] == int(id_num):
                add_sales(album, date, int(sales))
```

Here is my first attempt (not working):

```
class Album:
    """defines the class Album.
    Data attributes: id_num of album,
                     name of album,
                     band who wrote album,
                     price of the album.
    """


    def __init__(self, id_num, name, band, price):
        """creates and new album object, a dictionary with keys id_num, 
        name, band, and price"""
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.name = name
        self.band = band
        self.price = price
        self.album_dict = {}
        values = [int(self.id_num), self.name, self.band, float(self.price), 
                  0, None, None]
        keys = ['id_num', 'name', 'band', 'price', 'total_sales', 
                'first_date_recorded', 'last_date_recorded']
        for i in range(len(keys)):
            self.album_dict[keys[i]] = values[i]

    def add_sales(self,):
        """updates the given album dictionary by incrementing the 
        total_sales value by the given number of sales for that day"""
        if self.album_dict['first_date_recorded'] == None:
            self.album_dict['first_date_recorded'] = self.date
            self.album_dict['last_date_recorded'] = self.date
        elif self.date > self.album_dict['last_date_recorded']:
            self.album_dict['last_date_recorded'] = self.date
        elif self.date < self.album_dict['first_date_recorded']:
            self.album_dict['first_date_recorded'] = self.date
            self.album_dict['total_sales'] += self.daily_sales

    def __str__(self):
        """Prints the given album in a format where the first and last lines 
        are both made of 40 hyphen ('-') characters"""
        print('-' * 40)
        print('Album Name: {}'.format(self.album['name']))
        print('Band: {}'.format(self.album['band']))
        print('Purchase Price: ${:.2f}'.format(self.album['price']))
        print('First Recorded Sale: 
             {}'.format(self.album['first_date_recorded']))
        print('Last Recorded Sale: 
             {}'.format(self.album['last_date_recorded']))
        print('Total Sold: {}'.format(self.album['total_sales']))
        print('-' * 40)

def extract_album(lines, index):
    """takes a list of lines and an index into that list and returns a 
    album dictionary"""
    id_num, name, band, price = lines[(index + 1):(index + 5)]
    album_dict = make_album(id_num, name, band, price)
    return album_dict

def extract_all_albums(lines):
    """returns a list of albums in the same order as they are encountered 
    input lines list"""
    album_dict_list = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line == '<album>':
            album = extract_album(lines, i)
            album_dict_list.append(album)
    return album_dict_list

def read_sales(lines, albums):
    """locates the sales section if there is one and for each sales record 
    it should call the add_sales function on the appropriate album to update 
    the number of albums sold"""
    start_tag = 0
    end_tag = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line == '<sales>':
            start_tag = i
        elif line == '</sales>':
            end_tag = i
    for line in lines[(start_tag + 1):(end_tag)]:
        date, id_num, sales = line.split(',')
        for album in albums:
            if album['id_num'] == int(id_num):
                add_sales(album, date, int(sales))
```

There are a few things in my attempt that I know are wrong, but I can't seem to get my head around OOP and so struggle to construct classes and methods without a guide. I also haven't gone through and appended any calls to functions that are now classes and methods yet as I know the program won't work. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the class to work, the input parameter `self` needs to be in every single method (function) in your class. So you would need to revise the `extract_album`, `extract_all_albums`, and `read_sales` function to have `self` as the first function input. For example, `extract_album` would have to be re-written as:

```
def extract_album(self, lines, index):
    """takes a list of lines and an index into that list and returns a 
    album dictionary"""
    self.id_num, self.name, self.band, self.price = lines[(index + 1):(index + 5)]
    album_dict = make_album(self.id_num, self.name, self.band, self.price)
    return album_dict
```

Comment: The question specifications state otherwise, the idea being that add_sales becomes a method but other functions stay as such: "After those steps, your code should still define extract_album, extract_all_albums,  and read_sales functions, but the add_sales function should now be method of the class Album."